# Getting invalid json primitive error in jquery-ajax

Tags: json, jquery

I am using Jquery Ajax for calling the methods in controller, but i am always getting  invalid json primitive error.

**Below is the Code.**

**Client side Code**

```
$("#something >li").each(function () {
                    widgetsobj.push({
                    WidgetId: $(this).attr("dbid"),
                    ColumnNumber: 2,
                    RowNumber: 3,
                    WidgetType: "Graph",
                    WidgetName: "ddd",
                    PageName : "Page1"
                });
            });

 $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/ABC",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: { pagename1: pagename, widgetsobj1: JSON.stringify(widgetsobj) },
            success: function (data) {
                alert("ss");
            },
            error: function (data) {
                debugger;
            }
        });
```

**at controller**

```
[HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
 public JsonResult ABC(string pagename1, List<XYZ> widgetsobj1)
{

  // do something
}
```

Note XYZ is object with below properties.

- WidgetId
- ColumnNumber
- RowNumber
- WidgetType
- WidgetName
- PageName

So please let me know where i am wrong.

Comment: Dave Ward has written up a lengthly explanation of this at [http://encosia.com/asmx-scriptservice-mistake-invalid-json-primitive/](http://encosia.com/asmx-scriptservice-mistake-invalid-json-primitive/)

Answer (score 0):

The thing about ajax is that it is very picky about what you send through. You need to make absolutely sure that everything is in the correct format.

i.e. you are using double quotations (") rather than single (') and so on.

The best thing to do, would be to use Firebug or a similar console to view the POST as it is executed or to use `alert()` to view the POST data before it is sent off. That way you can identify where the problem is.

Remember, when you use `json.stringify()` it is going to turn whatever you feed it into what it believes will be an acceptable JSON string and because it is just a string there could be syntax errors at any point!

From what I can see here, there may be an issue at:

```
data: { pagename1: pagename, widgetsobj1: JSON.stringify(widgetsobj) }
```

You may want to try:

```
data: { "pagename1": pagename, "widgetsobj1": JSON.stringify(widgetsobj) }
```

Comment: ji jack i already tried this but not working. any how thanks for quick reply

Comment: Could you please post your POST data string here so that we can try to find the error. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. My solution was to add:

```
dataType: 'json',
```

to the ajax call.  Looks like you already had that in in your ajax call. But Hope this helps someone else.